# Angular JS formate date

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive

Is there any directive in Angular, I want to enable user when he write 2/3/67 in input for date date needs to be formatted like 02/03/1967 I tried few things on my own but they didn't work.

Comment: You should write a small directive using [momentJS](http://momentjs.com/) to parse and format. Look also how to use properly [ngModelController API](http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/type/ngModel.NgModelController)

Comment: @glepretre do you have an example for my case?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just add a Angularjs formating, when displaying users input like so

```
{{yourdate.variable | date:'yyyy-MM-dd'}}
```

Se more at [AnguarJS date function](http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/filter/date)

**EDIT**

Here is working [Plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/NzeauIDVHlgeb6qF75hX?p=preview), with different type of dates. Enjoy

Comment: How to do this on input when user is typing? for example here is my input   <input name="dob" placeholder="mm/dd/yyyy" type="text"  class="tx form-control" ng-model="birthdate"required />

Comment: I would n`t let user to write a date, u should make a field, when i click on it, it shows up a calendar and you can choose date in there.

Comment: But lets asume that I want from user to be able to write date ?